# import csv to mysql with java

Tags: java, csv, recover

so i have a csv file, and want to import it to mysql, so far in phpmyadmin i can import it with the following line:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Angel Silva\\Documents\\test.csv' INTO TABLE registros FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

my java program is:

```
public class recover {
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        String filename ="C:\\Users\\Angel Silva\\Documents\\test.csv";
        String query=null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gg", "root", "");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        query = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Angel Silva\\Documents\\test.csv' INTO TABLE registros FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'";
        stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);   
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(recover.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(recover.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(recover.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(recover.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

i get the following errors:

```
ene 24, 2016 1:28:33 PM recover main
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data tha there were input columns
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3206)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1232)
at recover.main(recover.java:29)
```

as i already have said if i input the sentence from the query directly into phpymyadmin i can recover the table but in java doesnt work

any idea what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
```

(as it's Windows)

Comment: Ivan Skalauh thx, but now only recovers the first row of the table, how can i recover the whole table? thx

Comment: Hmm the problem is still with line terminators. Try just \r, or remove the LINES TERMINATED BY statement completely (MySQL might be able to detect it automatically).

Answer (score 0):

so finally after reading mysql doc i modified the code as:

```
query="LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Angel Silva\\\\Documents\\\\251.csv' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

you must try by appending the table columns names to the query string

```
" LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Angel Silva\\Documents\\251.csv' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' (col1,col2,col3) ";
```

In my case it solved the problem...